# How to get all actions name on Xcode action editor in sks file "SpriteKit action"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I've a SpriteKit action file with some actions inside.

[image]

To use one action, I use:

```
let action = SKAction(named: "Shake")
```

**Instead** is possible to use directly the name inside **MyActions.sks** file?
**Something like:**

```
let actions = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyActions.sks")`  
let shakeAction = actions.listOfAction.Shake //this is my guess
```

If I print the scene file:

```
let actions = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyActions.sks")
print(actions)
```

**the output is:**

```
Optional({
    "_info" =     {
        "_previewScenePath" = "PippiPompiere/GameScene.sks";
    };
    actions =     {
        PlayerIdle1 = "<SKGroup: 0x79e60ec0>";
        PlayerMoveToHouse0 = "<SKGroup: 0x7b1ea010>";
        PlayerMoveToHouse1 = "<SKGroup: 0x7b052cd0>";
        PlayerMoveToHouse2 = "<SKGroup: 0x7b1ebbd0>";
        Rotate360 = "<SKGroup: 0x79e61710>";
        Shake = "<SKGroup: 0x79e60a10>";
        SunShake = "<SKGroup: 0x7b1e8620>";
        WaterJet = "<SKGroup: 0x7b1e8ce0>";
    };
})
(lldb)
```

is possible to have actions like an array?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can get the **actions** dictionary from the `.sks` file. Here, I have a `MyCustomActions.sks` file with an action **Pulse**.

```
guard
    let node = SKNode(fileNamed: "MyCustomActions"),
    let actions = node.value(forKey: "actions") as? [String:SKAction],
    let pulse = actions["Pulse"]
else { return }

print(pulse.duration)  // 0.6 seconds
```

From here, you can implement your own `struct` from the `actions` dictionary.

To get all the name of actions,

```
let actionNames = actions.map { $0.key }  // ["Pulse"]
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try, but you must remember the position of the action everytime? It's the same with a struct of string with the name of the actions?

Comment: Im not quite understand your question here. If there is an action in the SKNode (not run action), the node always have "action" KVO. I mention about the struct is in case you want to bind them later to get dot properly.

Comment: I was thrilled to think this might work, but sadly it does not.  I still haven't found a way to get references of actions out of a timeline.

I'd love to be able to have a way to 'go to a point in time' on a scene's timeline.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create an actions file (from the XCode template chooser or using the 'createAction -> NewFile' option in your GameScene.sks file).

The name of the action file does not matter; any action you create in such a file is available through SKAction(named:)

```
 if let shake = SKAction(named: "Shake") {
                myNode.run(shake)
            }
```