# Accessing an action defined in Scene Editor

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have an app using SpriteKit, which transitions between different Scenes on user input. I have defined all Scenes in separate `.sks` files and each contains a Sprite with a transition SKAction (`AnimateWithTextures` Action from within the Object Library).

What I want to do, is to enable the user to set the transition duration in settings. For this, I need access to the SKAction from the scene, but can't seem to find a way to access it programmatically. I know I can set a key when running an action from code with `run: withKey:`, but can I set this key from within Scene Editor?

Comment: The answer to this question also contains code for pulling out an action from a scene: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353120/how-to-get-all-actions-name-on-xcode-action-editor-in-sks-file-spritekit-action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are placing Actions onto the SKScene file, then it will fire at the timeline provided,  you will not be able to grab and hold it.  But what you can do, is on the timeline table in your scene file, is do CMD + click on your desired action.  and save it as a reference.  This will create an sks file that will house your actions.

Now that you have the actions in an action file, you can use `SKAction(named:"actionname")` to pull it out.

If it is an action you are going to be using over and over,  I would recommend storing this into a variable, and just calling the variable when needed.

Comment: Ok, I refactored the "in" and "out" transitions to a separate file and add them to the scene via the Object Library. I can access them in code, but when I change the duration in `didMove(to view: SKView)` with `intro.duration = 1`, it doesn't work. Am I changing it in the wrong function or is my whole approach wrong?

Comment: is intro your fading in an out effect?

Comment: I also tried accessing the action, changing its duration and then manually running it via the `run` function, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: No, it's not a fade in/out, it's a custom animation with textures.

Comment: if you want the duration to change, you use `SKAction(named:"actionname",duration:newDuration)`

Comment: Ah, yes, that did the job! Please update your answer.